# I am unable to download sdk manager in my window system

Tags: java, android, sdk, appium

I have downloaded sdk kit for android from below url "https://developer.android.com/studio/"...inside of that i am unable to find sdk manager for installation...Here i am sharing the screen shots for downloaded folder and zip folder site...[Site for sdk download](https://i.stack.imgur.com/efhaB.png).....[Downloaded folder details](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R7vSh.png)

Comment: you need to provide Android SDK folder path to Android studio -> settings -> SDK location

Comment: i have seen many videos they are saying that no need of sdk studio...we need to install sdk kit only...is it ryt...correct me if i am wrong

Comment: yes thats right but you can add it explicitly also. But its always better to add it at the time of installation.

Comment: okay,but here the problem ids while we are downloading sdk kit that folder should contains two more tools like sdk manager or something else....m unable to see that ...in my downloaded folder

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can install Android Studio from here https://developer.android.com/studio/archive in your machine.Inside Android studio, you will get the SDK Manager.
Path for accessing the SDK manager in Android Studio is shown in below image:
[image]
If you still need any info , reach me out.